# How to show that there is an equivalent context-free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

How can I show that for every context free grammar G, there is an equivalent context-free grammar that has production rules with these forms only:

$C→x $WV or $C → λ$, where $x$ is a terminal and $W$ and $V$ are variables.

The permitted rules look similar to Greibach Normal Form where all productions have form: $A → aV_1V_2\dots V_k$ only if $k = 2$ though. However, I'm not sure if that's the correct way to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with Greibach NF seems not that bad, if you take this for granted then start with this normal form (I assume there are no $\varepsilon$-productions, otherwise some cases must be considered) and then replace iteratively each production
$$
 V \mapsto aV_1 V_2 \cdots V_k
$$
with 
$$
 V \mapsto aV_1 [V_2 \cdots V_k], \quad
 [V_2 \cdots V_k] \mapsto bW_1W_2\cdots W_l V_3 \cdots V_k
$$
where $[V_2 \cdots V_k]$ denotes a new non-terminal, and $V_2 \mapsto b W_1 W_2 \cdots W_l$ (where this should be done for each such production starting in $V_2$, and these productions should be removed too). As there are just a finite number of productions this procedure terminates with a grammar of the required form.

Comment: Would there be a way to solve it without using Greibach Normal Form?

Comment: Of course, often in such problems it helps to do some simple examples and then often a general pattern will emerge. Have you tried to convert some simple grammars? And where did you stuck?

Comment: Yes. I converted some context-free grammars using substitution, removing unit productions, removing repeated productions. I'm just not sure how to show that every grammar can have 2 production rules of those forms only.

Comment: The answer given is a good start, but I am afraid that iteratively removing productions will yield longer and longer productions. The construction given will not end? Instead consider $V\to a[V_1\dots V_k]$ and $[V_1\dots V_k] \to b[W_1\dots W_\ell][V_2\dots V_k]$. Omit $[V_2\dots V_k]$ when empty, i.e., $k=1$.  Since we are required to have *exactly* two nonterminals at each right hand side we might add dummy variables $D$ with $D\to\lambda$ as allowed by the grammar format in the question.